# How to show hide a panelgroup on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jsf, checkbox

I have a panelgroup which has an outputText and an href link. I want this panelgroup to render based on checkbox value in below manner

1. panelgroup should render when value of checkbox is checked(true) on
   pageload.
2. If value of checkbox is not checked by default (on pageLoad), then
   panelgroup should not be visible but if user has clicked on checkbox
   the panelgroup should be visible.

**Problem**: If the checkbox is not checked by default and user clicks on checkbox then panelgroup is not being displayed. I think because it was not rendered at pageload therefore onClick it is not able to find any span to hide/show

Here Is panelgroup code :

```
<h:panelGroup
                                    styleClass="showMsg#{valNumber}"
                                    rendered="#{dataItem.checkboxVal}">

                                    <h:outputText
                                        styleClass="showMsg#{valNumber}"
                                        style="margin-top: 18px; text-align: center;"
                                        value="Text Line1" escape="false"
                                        rendered="#{dataItem.checkboxVal}" />
                                    <f:verbatim>
                                        <br />
                                    </f:verbatim>
                                    <h:outputText
                                        styleClass="showMsg#{valNumber}"
                                        style="text-align: center;" value="Text Line 2"
                                        escape="false"
                                        rendered="#{dataItem.checkboxVal}" />
                                    <f:verbatim>
                                        <br />
                                        <wps:urlGeneration
                                            <a id="xyz" href="<%wpsURL.write(out);%>">ContactUs</a>
                                        </wps:urlGeneration>
                                    </f:verbatim>
                                </h:panelGroup>
```

If i click on checkbox, then the panelgroup is not being displayed. Here is my click javascript function.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="xyz" styleClass='mycheckbox#{valNumber}' 
onclick="showShippingMsg(this,'#{valNumber}' ); "



   function showShippingMsg(checkbox, valNum){

        if(checkbox.checked){
            $(".showMsg"+valNum).css("display", "block");
         } else {
         $(".showMsg"+valNum).css("display", "none");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSF ajax to submit the checkbox value to the bean and re-render a part of your page. A common mistake is trying to rerender the same element, which has the rendered attribute. In this case, if your initial rendered value is `false`, then your panelGroup won't be rendered at all. So the ajax rerender won't find the referenced ID in the DOM.

I used to create a wrapper element with an ID, which is always rendered, so I can reference it's ID in the ajax render attribute. When ajax fires the render, it can update it's child element, which is optionally rendered.

A simple example bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("test")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1064219566884774973L;

    private boolean checkboxValue;

    public void setCheckboxValue(boolean checkboxValue) {
        this.checkboxValue = checkboxValue;
    }

    public boolean getCheckboxValue() {
        return checkboxValue;
    }
}
```

And the xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head />
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{test.checkboxValue}" >
                <f:ajax event="change" render="wrapper"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{test.checkboxValue}">
                <h:outputText value="Checkbox selected" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
</html>
```

An alternative solution, if you don't need the checkbox value in the bean is to use it only on client-side. This xhtml doesn't use any backing bean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head />
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{checkboxItem}" >
                <f:ajax event="change" render="wrapper"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{checkboxItem.value}">
                <h:outputText value="Checkbox selected" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use JSF ajax functionality.
Here is the sample code:

```
<h:panelGroupid="panel">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.checkboxValue}">
        <!-- your content here -->
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checkboxValue}">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="panel"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Now, when the checkbox value change true to false or false to true (when you click on it), ajax will fire setter method for checkboxValue in your bean and will initiate re-rendering on your JSF component with id set in render attribute (in this case `id="panel"`) and it should be rendered if checkboxValue is true. So if checkboxValue is true, `h:panelGroup` attribute rendered will be true as well and vice versa.

And in your bean checkboxValue should be set something like this:

```
public boolean checkboxValue;

public void setCheckboxValue(boolean checkboxValue) {
    this.checkboxValue = checkboxValue;
}

public boolean getCheckboxValue() {
    return this.checkboxValue;
}
```

Makes sense ?

**EDIT**

Note, that `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` component should be nested inside `h:form` in order to POST your checkboxValue to the bean.

**EDIT 2**

In case of using ajax, you should try to re-render the whole dataTable (not really a good idea if dataTable stores lots of data). If that's not working for you, you can try to set styleClass for panel group to something like this `styleClass="your_panel_style_class#{valNumber} #{not dataItem.checkboxVal ? 'style_class_to_hide_panel' : ''}"` this will set base styleClass based on `checkboxVal`. And then get rid of `rendered` attribute on your panel.

```
.style_class_to_hide_panel {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can try to put this in onlcick attribute for your checkbox

```
function togglePanel(valNumber) {
    var panel = $('.your_panel_style_class' + valNumber);

    if (panel === undefined) {
        // find your panel and select it
    }

    panel.toggleClass('style_class_to_hide_panel');
}
```

Not sure how reliable jQuery script will be for you.

Comment: I am working on a existing code and my piece of code lies inside <f:subview> in below hierarchy. <table><tr><h:dataTable><h:column><f:subview>

Answer (score 0):

I tried below approach and it is working fine.

```
<h:panelGroup

style="#{dataItem.checkboxVal ? 'display:block;':'display:none;'}"
styleClass="showMsg#{valNumber}">

<h:outputText
styleClass="showMsg#{valNumber}"
style="margin-top: 18px; text-align: center;"
value="Text Line1" escape="false"/>

<h:outputText
styleClass="showMsg#{valNumber}"
style="text-align: center;" value="Text Line 2"
escape="false"/>
<f:verbatim>
<wps:urlGeneration
<a id="xyz" href="<%wpsURL.write(out);%>">ContactUs</a>
                                        </wps:urlGeneration>
                                    </f:verbatim>
                                </h:panelGroup>
```